# Directive similar spreadsheet with bad performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, matrix, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a directive which is gonna work similar to an excel.
As Javascript does not support matrix as native, I had to do the workaround that usually people does. Array inside array.

Everything is working so far, but I've realized that when I applies a matrix of 100x100 I do have a big problema with performance. With a small matrix it's ok, but with big ones it's pissing me off.

Another big deal for me is that while this directive does not finish its loading the rest of the APP does not load if the problematic directive does not finish.

How can I improve this my current approach to have a better performance? And
How can I make the APP to load each part of itself in an asynchronous way?

From my service I have this:

```
this.getDataGrid = function(column, row){

    var matrix = new Array(column);

    for (var i = 0; i < column; i++) {
       matrix[i] = new Array(row);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
       for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
          matrix[i][j] = {value: '', checked: false};
       }
    }

    return matrix;

};
```

From my directive:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.dataGrid = info.getDataGrid(attrs.column, attrs.row);
}
```

From my view:

```
<table border="1">

    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="items in dataGrid track by $index">
            <td><strong>{{$index+1}}</strong></td>
            <td ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"><input type="text" ng-model="item.value"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

I gave a try to quick-ng-repeat as mentioned by **apairet**, but didn't work so far. Looks like the quick-ng-repeat doesn't work with nested array.

```
    <tr quick-ng-repeat="item in dataGrid" quick-repeat-list="items">
        <td><strong>{{$index+1}}</strong></td>
        <td quick-ng-repeat="subItem in items" quick-repeat-list="subItems"><input type="text" ng-model="subItems.value"/></td>
    </tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

After some research I started to go throughout to the lazy load approach. I've found some projects with RequireJS and Sript.js and I thought this was the solution for my problem, until I realize I had a diff situation.

The lazy load approach works by a route, it loads the related files of the route in a lazy way.

However, what about when you have inside the view of your route a directive which makes everything slow? That's my case.

So, I had to do some workaround as it follows below:

**DIRECTIVE**

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

    var maxIntervalColumnLoad = 5;
    var maxIntervalRowLoad = 5;

    scope.gridLoadColumn = function(index){
        if (index <= maxIntervalColumnLoad) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    scope.gridLoadRow = function(index){
        if (index <= maxIntervalRowLoad) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    $interval(function(){
        maxIntervalColumnLoad = (maxIntervalColumnLoad + 5);
    }, 1500, (attrs.column/maxIntervalColumnLoad) );

    $interval(function(){
        maxIntervalRowLoad = (maxIntervalRowLoad + 5);
    }, 1500, (attrs.row/maxIntervalRowLoad) );

    scope.dataGrid = info.generateDataGrid(attrs.column, attrs.row);

  }
```

**VIEW**

> ```
> <thead>
>     ...
> </thead>
>
> <tbody>
>     <tr ng-if="gridLoadRow($index)" ng-repeat="items in dataGrid track by $index">
>         <td><strong>{{$index+1}}</strong></td>
>         <td ng-if="gridLoadColumn($index)" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"><input type="text" ng-model="item.value"/></td>
>     </tr>
> </tbody>
> ```

It solved the problem with my first load page.

But I still have performance problems when I'm typing any value in the inputs.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value" />
```

I'm guessing the relation through the ng-model seems to be the problem, but I need it to keep the data sync.

Any idea how could it be achieve? Or How to improve the performance?

Comment: did you had a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ ?

Comment: I know this ng-grid, but initially my choice for a custom grid was because this is gonna be very custom. Ng-grid did not fit for me. The quantity of custom staff I would do with this ng-grid does not pay off.

Comment: And it is not a big deal to make a simple one. Few lines of code I think is enough. I just need some ideas to improve. Ng-grid is gonna be the last option.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat. At least before angular 1.2 and track by, it made a difference.

Comment: Wow! it looks very interesting. I'll give a try. I'll let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like this quick repeat doesn't work with nested array. Simply show only 1 column and 1 row. I'll update my question with my try.